# How to update a SQL Server database from Labwindows CVI

Tags: c, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a SQL Server database from CVI. I have the code:

```
    UPDATE [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel]
    SET [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel].[Contents] = [LabIC].[dbo].[TolvasSABAMEX2].[Material]
    FROM [LabIC].[dbo].[TolvasSABAMEX2]
    WHERE [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel].[VesselID] = [LabIC].[dbo].[TolvasSABAMEX2].[id]
```

**I use this code from SQL Server and it works, but when used in CVI does not update:**

```
int CVICALLBACK actualizar_i (int panel, int control, int event,
    void *callbackData, int eventData1, int eventData2)
{
    switch (event)
    {
      case EVENT_COMMIT:
         conexion2();

         int tolva;
         char material[26];
         //float valor;


         GetCtrlVal(panel, PANEL_2_RING, &tolva);
         GetCtrlVal(panel, PANEL_2_STRING, &material[0]);
         //GetCtrlVal(panel, PANEL_2_NUMERIC, &valor);

         char comando[500]={0};
        sprintf(comando, "UPDATE TolvasSABAMEX2 SET Contents = %s WHERE id = %u", material, tolva);

         int hstmt; 
         hstmt=DBPrepareSQL(hdbc, comando);
         DBExecutePreparedSQL (hstmt);

         //sprintf(comando2"UPDATE [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel] SET [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel].[Contents] = [LabIC].[dbo].[TolvasSABAMEX2].[Material] FROM [LabIC].[dbo].[TolvasSABAMEX2] WHERE [eBob].[dbo].[tblVessel].[VesselID] = [LabIC].[dbo].[TolvasSABAMEX2].[id]");
         break;
}        //UPDATE [LabIC].[dbo].[TolvasSABAMEX2] SET Contents = %s WHERE [LabIC].[dbo].[TolvasSABAMEX2].[id] = %u", material, tolva
return 0;
```

**And been using the following commands SQLToolkit CVI but I do not work DBPrepareSQL, DBActivateSQL**

Comment: Did you post this by accident here and were you looking for [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: LOL, so literally unclear what you are asking  :D

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105719/can-questions-be-asked-in-spanish-on-stack-overflow

Comment: What are the data types of the `Contents` and `Id` columns? You may need to enclose the values in quotes. For more about SQL injection, see [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).